# FluentValidation in Blazor: how to pass Dependency into custom validator

Tags: fluentvalidation, blazor-client-side

I am using FluentValidation in Blazor WebAssembly Project.
I need to pass HttpClient into FluentValidation to do Email check ?
How do i go about it?

```
 <EditForm Model="_editprofileModel" OnValidSubmit="UpdateProfile">
            <FluentValidator TValidator="EditProfileValidator"  />

            <ValidationSummary />
 ...........
</EditForm>
```

I want to do something like this, but it give compiler Error "the name _Http does not exist in the current context

```
<FluentValidator TValidator="EditProfileValidator(_Http)"  />
```

Comment: Can't you just `@inject` it into the Component?

Comment: it is already injected into component, but need to pass the injected instance to the validator.

Comment: Is `<FluentValidator />` a component you have access to? Can you pass _http as a `[Parameter]`?